# Async load angular controllers and factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, browserify, webpack

I am building an angular app. The app has grown too large and my index,html is bombarded with 80+ javascript files. I bundled and minified JS files but loading all the script files at app startup is not a good idea.

How could I load scripts only when they are required?

Comment: A module loader wouldn't help with reducing the number of files to be loaded. It would still load the exact same files at page load. Usually a minifier combines the files into one file, did you minify each file individually instead?

Comment: Downvoted for Off topic cause opinion-based.

Comment: I dont want all of my javascript files to be loaded at app startup. Is there any way to load files such as angular controllers and factories asynchronously when they are required?

Comment: Removed my downvote since you now have changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading with AngularJS is not as simple as downloading the files on demand. Angular normally require all its components like modules, directives, services upfront except for templates which can be downloaded async.

There are multiple solutions out there for this particular problem. [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) being one of them.

You can use ocLazyLoad to download controllers, modules, services when needed. There is also support of routing using angular-ui router with ocLazyLoad. You can even combine ocLazyLoad and RequireJS which allows you to use Require's r.js optimizer for concatenating files as per modules with least configurations.

OcLazyLoad has good examples for different cases in the link I sahred above but I have also made a sample [Angular-Boilerplate](https://github.com/vishwanatharondekar/angular-boilerplate) which has basic structure and Gruntfile which has tasks for combining the modules. *(I should add some documentation for the boilerplate thogh)*